# Red border around apps in the store

Tags: store

I'm running WP 7.8. Occasionally when I'm browsing the store I'll see an app which has a red border around it, although when viewing the app page directly (as opposed to in a list with other apps) the red border does not appear.

I don't seem to have any trouble downloading the apps (so its not indicating WP8 only apps - they don't even appear) and I can download a trial (so not indicating purchase only apps).

A few examples which I'm seeing with red borders:

- Pocket God
- Dream Sleuth
- Go Shopping

Anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call this "the red stripe deals" and the apps (always three simultaneously) are sold for a lower price for a limited time when they have the red stripe.

You can see the current red stripe deals in the collection in the Store:http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/collections/red-stripe-deals/db534788-8a1a-4f31-9a1d-bd9bdeddc467

Answer (score 1):

+1

Red Stripe Deals mean it gives you three choices every week to renew their Windows Phone experience and you can get 50% discount on the original price of one favorite app, one indie game and another one Xbox game.

Hope it helps.